# Phoengap App for iOS and Android - how to set the asset/www folder

Tags: cordova

because I am trying to make an App by phonegap, what should run on iOS and Android and maybe other devices like Windows as well I have a small understanding question about the struckture of the assets folder.

In the docu is staying, that everythign what is in the assets/www forlder is coming from me. HTML/JS/CSS images etc.

But what will happen, when I have small diferences between the iOS App and the Android App expecially in the design. Should I pack everythign in the www folder and make everytime check, if iOS then this, and if Android then this or should I make separate folders for example assets/www/android and assets/www/iOS and have there the different codes and images for each platform or make it like Wikipedia: https://github.com/wikimedia/WikipediaMobile

In Wikipedia's App in the www folder there are subfolders for each platform, where there are properties for this plattform. This, what I don't understand is how they select which platform is used and how knows the App on iOS to select the properties form the iOS forlder?

Has anyone experience with this?

Answer (score 1):

I mostly use prebuild scripts where there are real differences between the platforms - most stuff is constant, but a few files get swapped out when copying from the development www folder ( which itself is generated with jekyll ) to the app www folder - for example cordova.android.js gets copied as cordova.js.

This approach also allows handling some of the larger inconsistencies between platforms such as video needing to be in res rather than assets on android.

Most of the design differences can be handled with CSS media queries.

Custom plugins can also be useful - they can have the same interface on all platforms, but completely different implementation.

If you do end up having to switch something in javascript at run time, just check device.platform.

Comment: I thing the Wikipedia example is one of the best how to handle this different devices. Do yo have take a look there?

Comment: It's a little overengineered for my taste, and deploying all files to the device then choosing from them with javascript doesn't seem like the best approach when you know that only one of them will ever be used.

Comment: Hey Tom, what is your suggestion? To make 3 phonegap projects and put the files for each platform only? Is this split becoming more performance?

Comment: The one thing what I thought if I have only one project is to make an local variable what kinf of device it is and store this permanent in the DB of the device. After that If this variable is set I will not make anymore the check what kind of platform it is. What do you mean?

Comment: I do have separate projects set up for iOS and android - as soon as you do anything with custom plugins you need that anyway. However, the common components (mainly stuff in the www folder) are copied from a single codebase by the build script.

Comment: Hi Tom, thanks for sharing your experience. I thing your solution ist very good.

Answer (score 0):

To work with PhoneGap and on different platform, I create different folder : page, plugin, function... All this folder are similar on all platform. This allow you to copy them in a different platform and to see your application running. Just don't copy the cordova.js file.

In each specific function, like Tom, I check the device.platform to adjust the code. But I try to get the most generic code. Be carefull, sometimes the platform don't interpret basic code (like in windows Phone the balise bottom...)

If you use plugins, just don't put it in the same folder as your project one.

When I developed with phonegap, this was my strategy:

-Develop on Android my application, test it

-Copy with a software like diffmerge, the www folder of android in iosproject

-Build ios project, test it